# What command did git do with "git reset --har"

Tags: git

I missed the tab key before pressing enter on my local git branch, I ended up executing:

```
git reset --har
```

versus the intended

```
git reset --hard
```

Usually git complains when running a command that appears to be mistyped. I looked through the --help for git reset and found no args for "h","a","r".

It seems to have run the hard reset, What did it actually run? Or if it ran "--hard" why?

*additional info:
sylvesterjakubowski$ git --version
git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37) #on mountain lion.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is as per the [`gitcli`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcli.html) doc page:

> many commands allow a long option "--option" to be abbreviated only to
>   their unique prefix (e.g. if there is no other option whose name
>   begins with "opt", you may be able to spell "--opt" to invoke the
>   "--option" flag), but you should fully spell them out when writing
>   your scripts; later versions of Git may introduce a new option whose
>   name shares the same prefix, e.g. "--optimize", to make a short prefix
>   that used to be unique no longer unique.

Also on the same page:

> Commands that support the enhanced option parser accepts unique prefix
>   of a long option as if it is fully spelled out, but use this with a
>   caution. For example, git commit --amen behaves as if you typed git
>   commit --amend, but that is true only until a later version of Git
>   introduces another option that shares the same prefix, e.g `git commit
>   --amenity" option.

So yeah, it ran `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 3):

It did not run the equivalent of `-h -a -r` because there are two preceding dashes, not one.

Git may be implementing an algorithm here to allow you to use the shortest unique match for a long flag name. Since no long flags for `git reset` start with `--har`, it could have then treated the request as unambiguous and proceeded to run `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage, do not rely on the abbreviated option names the parse-options API offers, to protect you from an abbreviated form of an option that used to be unique within the command getting non-unique when a new option that share the same
prefix is added.

See [commit b02e7d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b02e7d5d701a6217a3a522d9169b483b25c262dc) (12 Apr 2019), and [commit effc2ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/effc2bae642a08ea0cb4a9020cb57632d00ab1a0), [commit c4932b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4932b00f4da864f8b61881b75ca18826f461650), [commit f6188dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6188dccb7795ba7c374274264b70e5a4a2a2f5f), [commit ae0a11c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae0a11c20dd75f5955a25903020340096739b294), [commit 7076e44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7076e4422c0304a1c00f54e268e59dfd7c2ad510), [commit f927ae6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f927ae6c86cdc2b1b66b3c94e541f8045300d68f), [commit dd605e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd605e4956903da2e375afe2e58beab2af39b7b8) (25 Mar 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 39e4773](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39e4773daa758243ff3c708b024f39b7e47f0d7e), 22 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `tests`: disallow the use of abbreviated options (by default)
>
> Git's command-line parsers support uniquely abbreviated options, e.g.
>   `git init --ba` would automatically expand `--ba` to `--bare`.
>
> This is a very convenient feature in every day life for Git users, in particular when tab completion is not available.
>
> However, it is not a good idea to rely on that in Git's test suite, as something that is a unique abbreviation of a command line option today might no longer be a unique abbreviation tomorrow.
>
> For example, if a future contribution added a new mode `git init --babyproofing` and a previously-introduced test case used the fact that `git init --ba` expanded to `git init --bare`, that future contribution would now have to touch seemingly unrelated tests just to keep the test suite from failing.
>
> So let's disallow abbreviated options in the test suite by default.

For instance:

> ### tests (`rebase`): spell out the `--keep-empty` option
>
> This test wants to run `git rebase` with the `--keep-empty` option, but
>   it really only spelled out `--keep` and trusted Git's option parsing to
>   determine that this was a unique abbreviation of the real option.
>
> However, Denton Liu contributed a [patch series](https://public-inbox.org/git/cover.1553354374.git.liu.denton@gmail.com/) that introduces a new `git rebase` option called `--keep-base`, which makes this previously unique abbreviation non-unique.
>
> Whether this patch series is accepted or not, it is actually a bad practice to use abbreviated options in our test suite, because of the issue that those unique option names are not guaranteed to stay unique in the future.
>
> So let's just not use abbreviated options in the test suite.