# Why does git push --force-wit work but some other options don't?

Tags: git

When I execute `git push --force-wit` it seemingly is equivalent to `git push --force-with-lease`. Why do some git commands allow passing a prefix of a long option while others don't?

Comment: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcli.html — see the paragraph on shortening unique options: "Many commands allow a long option ... to be abbreviated only to their unique prefix"

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257324/what-command-did-git-do-with-git-reset-har

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten many options while they stay unambiguous, i.e. there's no other option that starts with the same string.

```bash
git status --no-b  # OK, interpreted as --no-branch
git status --no-   # Not OK, might be any of
                   # --no-ahead-behind       --no-long        --no-show-stash 
                   # --no-branch             --no-null        --no-untracked-files 
                   # --no-column             --no-porcelain   --no-verbose 
                   # --no-ignored            --no-renames             
                   # --no-ignore-submodules  --no-short
```

Future version of git might introduce new options, so don't rely on it much.

Comment: Not every option. No law says that this is required. Many git commands do permit it but "every" is unwarranted.